# How to emulate os.path.samefile behaviour on Windows and Python 2.7?

Tags: python, filesystems

Given two paths I have to compare if they're pointing to the same file or not. In Unix this can be done with `os.path.samefile`, but as documentation states it's not available in Windows.
What's the best way to emulate this function?
It doesn't need to emulate common case. In my case there are the following simplifications:

- Paths don't contain symbolic links.
- Files are in the same local disk.

Now I use the following:

```
def samefile(path1, path2)
    return os.path.normcase(os.path.normpath(path1)) == \
           os.path.normcase(os.path.normpath(path2))
```

Is this OK?

Comment: `>>> os.path.normcase(os.path.normpath(r"c:\users\aayoubi\desktop"))
'c:\\users\\aayoubi\\desktop'` i couldn't find cases where this would fail.

Comment: I just found one example. 'c:\\one\two' and 'c:\\one\two\' can point to the same directory, but this method would say they're different.

Comment: both outputs were the same:
`>>> os.path.normcase(os.path.normpath(r"c:\\one\two"))
'c:\\one\\two'`

`>>> os.path.normcase(os.path.normpath(r"c:\\one\two\\"))
'c:\\one\\two'`

Comment: Would you need to be able to handle network paths? e.g. (\\127.0.0.1\c$\test is equivalent to c:\test)

Comment: @Shawabawa, no. I mentioned that files are in the same _local_ disk.

Comment: Per [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.samefile),`os.path.samefile` is available for Windows as of Python 3.2.

Answer (score 5):

According to [issue#5985](http://bugs.python.org/issue5985) the os.path.samefile and os.path.sameopenfile are now in py3k. I verified this on Python 3.3.0

For older versions of Python here's a way which uses the [GetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

[see_if_two_files_are_the_same_file](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/see_if_two_files_are_the_same_file.html)

Answer (score 4):

The os.stat system call returns a tuple with a lot of information about each file - including creation and last modification time stamps, size, file attributes. The chances of different files having the same paramters are very slim. I think it is very resonable to do:

```
def samefile(file1, file2):
    return os.stat(file1) == os.stat(file2)
```

Comment: I guess it's technically possible for the file to be modified in between the two calls to stat. Comparing the path like he does in the question wouldn't have this problem

Comment: Yes, for random files such chances are very small. But I have a bunch of semi-automatically created files and many of them have the same size and time stamps.

Comment: I think that approach is likely to lead to hard-to-find bugs. This kind of case can occur when for example an archiver unpacks lots of files all with the same timestamps. If they are zero-byte files than one could end up with lots of false matches...

Comment: I believe this is essentially how `samefile` is implemented.  Except it only needs to compare `st_dev` and `st_ino` to _know_ if they are the same file or not.

Answer (score 4):

The real use-case of `os.path.samefile` is not symbolic links, but *hard* links. `os.path.samefile(a, b)` returns True if `a` and `b` are both hard links to the same file. They might not have the same path.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer in this thread.  But I use python on Windows, and ran into this issue today, found this thread, and found that `os.path.samefile` doesn't work for me.

So, to answer the OP, `now to emulate os.path.samefile`, this is how I emulate it:

```
# because some versions of python do not have os.path.samefile
#   particularly, Windows. :(
#
def os_path_samefile(pathA, pathB):
  statA = os.stat(pathA) if os.path.isfile(pathA) else None
  if not statA:
    return False
  statB = os.stat(pathB) if os.path.isfile(pathB) else None
  if not statB:
    return False
  return (statA.st_dev == statB.st_dev) and (statA.st_ino == statB.st_ino)
```

It is not as tight as possible, because I was more interested in being clear in what I was doing.

I tested this on Windows-10, using python 2.7.15.

Caveat:
`st_ino` & `st_dev` do not always have meaningful contents.
Observation on Windows10, Python 2.7.9: `st_ino` is always 0.
See older post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275731/os-stat-on-windows)

Comment: If `st_ino` is always 0, this function is utterly useless.