# Python os.st_uid only return value 0

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I'm using windows machine and python 3. I'm trying to get the user id from windows files:

```
import os
os.stat('filepath').st_uid
```

However this only returns st_uid = 0 which doesn't make sense.

Can someone please help? If I can't use st_uid, what else I can use to obtain the file user info?

Thanks!

---

Update: Thanks for the help guys. I end up using windows security API to obtain user information:

[Here is the link](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830618/how-to-find-the-owner-of-a-file-or-directory-in-python. Seems that that doesn't work with windows...

Comment: that will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086412/howto-determine-file-owner-on-windows-using-python-without-pywin32

Answer (score 2):

`os.stat()` on windows seems very limited: [os.stat() on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275731/os-stat-on-windows)

so id values are zeroed: you cannot use that to get the user id info.

But this Q & A gives most methods to do it in python: [Howto determine file owner on windows using python without pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086412/howto-determine-file-owner-on-windows-using-python-without-pywin32)

Note: this is a CW answer, as the question isn't really a duplicate of either of the linked answers, but this answer just links both aspects: the issue and the workarounds.